# Why can the blue colour in a rainbow be seen?

Tags: optics, visible-light, interference

In between a rainbow, the sky appears much brighter because all the colors can get reflected in the raindrop.

[image]

The maximum angles at which red light and blue light get reflected reflected are $42^{\circ}$ and  $40^{\circ}$ respectively.

[image: angles]

Why doesn't red interfere with blue? Shouldn't we see magenta?

Comment: Are you interpreting the ray diagram figure that you presented as meaning that blue light is reflected/refracted at all angles between 0˚ and 40˚ and red light at all angles between 0˚ and 42˚? If so, I don't think that that's true. I think that the diagram means that blue light and red light are reflected/refracted to angles at around 40˚ and 42˚, respectively.

Comment: I am pretty sure they do. That's why the rainbow is bright in the middle. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/atmos/ligsky.html#c1

Comment: 1) The first path taken by any color is the brightest one. 2) Other paths mix together all frequencies. So, not only is red mixed with blue, but with all other colors. Overall the initial decomposed color is restored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you have misinterpreted your last diagram.

[image]

There is no way that both the blue and the red rays can enter **one** eye simultaneously as they are diverging rays originating from the **same** water drpolet which is many hundreds/thousands of metres from the eye.

I have adapted your diagram into one which illustrates the passage of the blue and red rays from **two** water droplets into **one** eye.

[image]

Hopefully you will now comprehend why there is an angular separation of colours.

---

**Update** as a result of a comment made by @pernkDernets

Indeed the red light does travel along many paths (angles) but it is concentrated around $42^\circ$.
There is also blue light along that direction but the intensity of blue light is much less than that of the red light. 
What you observe from a particular direction is the predominant colour.

There is a very good explanation of this in the article entitled [Maths behind the rainbow](https://plus.maths.org/content/rainbows).

Comment: Thank for taking the time to draw that for me. But shouln't the red light take many paths - like i wrote, that's why the rainbow appears brighter on the inside. Because all colors reflect there, right?

The maximum angle that red light gets reflected is 42 degrees while blue light maximum is 40 degrees. So red light should also sometimes take the same paths as the blue. Or i am wrong? Here is a picture from wikiepdia: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/Rainbow_single_reflection.svg/220px-Rainbow_single_reflection.svg.png

Comment: @pernkDernets Indeed the red light does travel along many paths (angles) but it is concentrated around $42^\circ$. There is also blue light along that direction but the intensity of blue light is much less than that of the red light. There is a very good analysis here https://plus.maths.org/content/rainbows

Comment: i see this discussion about the deviation made a lot of sense to me. Thank you for explanation and the link! Can you make a new answer so i can give you the "accept answer"? This is what made me understand :)

Comment: @pernkDernets At your request I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The colors won't overlap because the wavelengths of both colors are different. White light contains all the visible light so when a prism, or water vapor, is in the sky then the visible light separates. When they separate they disperse so you can see colors.

Comment: The red light will take the same path as the blue light, and hence you should see magenta

Comment: @pernkDernets clearly, even in the diagram you've put in the question, the red and blue light follow different paths.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments :) but maybe it is a bad diagram. Red light should take many angles, that's why you see the rainbow is brighter in the middle. So the red light should also take the blue route, that's why i am confused. See this image here from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rainbow_single_reflection.svg